# Create glowing cracked stone-like sword texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I have no idea how to explain, but I want to make a texture like this:
[image: sword]

I'm using blender 2.79 with cycles render

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65801/can-i-access-a-meshs-local-vertex-positions-in-cycles-nodes/65803#65803

Comment: Ok, since nobody quiet answered your question, I re-post link to video tutorial I did when I started with blender. you can get an idea from that how to set up a texture and glowing overlay.
Its a three video tutorial you can skip to making the sword only. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyjSnak3Yjo